# 2nd monitor uses brightness setting from main - can't keep changes

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

Added HP monitor via HDMI to DisplayPort. Have AMD Radeon HD 7450 graphics card. HP monitor picks up default brightness setting from main ASUS VK278Q 27". I can adjust HP via monitor menu manually but not sticky and returns to ASUS settings after screensaver and every reboot.

Comment: How do you know it is returning to ASUS settings and not HP settings? Does the monitor have special drivers or a smart mode that can be disabled? What model is the HP monitor, the one with issues?  And I assume you meant you are changing the settings through the OSD?

Comment: Answering in order from above: I set the ASUS to something unique like 31% and boom that'd be the HP setting when next booted or revived from screensaver. HP w2338h, basic monitor, not high-end. No smart mode, but it does have a 2009 driver, the last update. No problems w/ it when on Win7 Ult. Now on Win 8.1. ASUS VK278Q. Yes, OSD

Comment: One more: The ASUS doesn't have a downloadable driver - uses the Microsoft Generic PnP from 2006